# Oracle SQL - earliest date from multiple date columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help. I have the query below but I do not think is working as expected.

The business rule is that Date1 must be the earliest date, if not then show all records where Date1 is not the earliest. I started with this query but I think it needs some twitching to work, could you please help.

```
SELECT f.id_number,f.status,E.Date1,E.Date2,E.Date3,E.Date4,E.Date5,E.Date6
CASE
    WHEN E.Date1 > E.Date2      THEN 'Date2'           || ' ' ||  E.Date2
    WHEN E.Date1 < E.Date3      THEN 'Date3'         || ' ' ||  E.Date3
    WHEN E.Date1 < E.Date4      THEN 'Date4'         || ' ' ||  E.Date4
    WHEN E.Date1 < E.Date5      THEN 'Date5'         || ' ' ||  E.Date5
    WHEN E.Date1 < E.Date6      THEN 'Date6'     || ' ' ||  E.Date6
         END AS THE_DATE
FROM
       TableE E
LEFT JOIN TableF F
       ON F.id_number = E.id_number  
WHERE E.Date1  IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: WHEN E.Date1 > E.Date2  Why is this one ">" when all the rest are "<"?

Comment: hi, this was typo during my testing of the query. I believe is ">"

Comment: Plz provide sample data to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This. Used the `LEAST()` function to get the earliest date.

```
  SELECT f.id_number,
   f.status,
   e.date1,
   e.date2,
   e.date3,
   e.date4,
   e.date5,
   e.date6,
   CASE
     WHEN Least (e.date1, e.date2, e.date3, e.date4, e.date5, e.date6) =
          date1 THEN
     To_char(e.date1)
     ELSE decode(Least(e.date1, e.date2), e.date1, '',
                                          ' Date2'
                                          || ' '
                                          || To_char(e.date2))
          || decode(Least(e.date1, e.date3), e.date1, '',
                                             ' Date3'
                                             || ' '
                                             || To_char(e.date3))
          || decode(Least(e.date1, e.date4), e.date1, '',
                                             ' Date4'
                                             || ' '
                                             || To_char(e.date4))
          || decode(Least(e.date1, e.date5), e.date1, '',
                                             ' Date5'
                                             || ' '
                                             || To_char(e.date5))
          || decode(Least(e.date1, e.date6), e.date1, '',
                                             ' Date6'
                                             || ' '
                                             || To_char(e.date6))
   END THE_DATE
FROM   (SELECT NVL(date2, date1),
           NVL(date3, date1),
           NVL(date4, date1),
           NVL(date5, date1),
           NVL(date6, date1) FROM TableE) E
   LEFT JOIN tablef F
          ON F.id_number = e.id_number
 WHERE  e.date1 IS NOT NULL;
```

Here is a sample data output

```
 ID_NUMBER STATUS DATE1    DATE2    DATE3    DATE4    DATE5    DATE6    THE_DATE                                                                  
---------- ------ -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1  TRUE  20-08-17 19-08-17 20-08-17 19-08-17 22-08-17 18-08-17  Date2 19-08-17 Date4 19-08-17 Date6 18-08-17
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question. How do I ignore null on the date columns? With the above query if the column is null then is populating the THE_DATE column. For example if the Date3 and Date4 are null it shows "Date3 Date4" under the THE_DATE column.

Comment: You can default the date2,date3..date6  to date1 if any of them is null.I have modified the query accordingly. However if date1 itself is null, then you will get no results.

Comment: Thank you so much. Much appreciated.